# (Standardese) Array size technical question

Tags: c++, arrays, language-lawyer, standards

We know that an array size must be a `constant expression`.
We also know that a `constant expression` can be evaluated at compile time, but there's no guarantee that it will be evaluated at compile time.

So now... Assuming `foo()` is usable as constant expression:
What happens if the compiler (for whatever reasons, really), doesn't evaluate the `foo()` call at compile time in this hypothetical scenario? How would the array "be initialized"? Would this be a case of VLA? Or would it be considered "An array of unknown bound"?

```cpp
int myArray[foo()]; // assume the compiler doesn't evaluate foo() at compile time, because it's not mandatory...?
```

EDIT: See this example:

```cpp
constexpr int foo() {
    // constexpr: CAN be evaluated at compile time
    // Not mandatory for it to BE evaluated at compile time (??)
    return 5;
    // A conforming compiler might still decide to evaluate this at run-time, no?

}

int main() {
    // A compiler might decide to NOT evaluate foo() at compile time
    // So what...?
    int myArray[foo()];
};
```

Comment: It will be evaluated at compile time when used in a context that requires a compile time value. Unlike `int x = foo();`, where it is up to the compiler.

Comment: Is the compiler mandated to evaluate it a compile time in this scenario? If so, can you show me where this is mandated? I'm really curious

Comment: "because it's not mandatory..." what do you mean? If `foo` cannot be evaluated at compile time then its an error. Did you try it? https://godbolt.org/z/rr4x9crqM (note that gcc has extensions enabled and needs flags to be conforming)

Comment: Well, cppreference states:
"Core Constant Expression: Defines an expression that can be evaluated at compile time.

Such expressions can be used as non-type template arguments, array sizes, and in other contexts that require constant expressions, e.g."

Nowhere can I see that the core constant expression "Must" be evaluated at compile time. So I think (??) that a compiler might still be able to not evaluate any constant expression at compile time if they so wished (??)

Comment: I updated my thread with an example similar to yours to describe what I am saying.

Comment: So then what is the answer to my question in that case?

Comment: The answer is "Such expressions can be used as ..., array sizes, ... that require constant expressions."

Comment: Even if the compiler does not evaluate them at compile time, then? Interesting

Comment: Cppreference uses ‘evaluate at compile time’ (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression) so I assume it would make some sense.

Comment: So tl;dr it doesn’t matter as long as it is a constant expression (which might or might not evaluate at compile time, according to cppref), correct?

Comment: In [expr.const] ❡1, Note #1 says: *Constant expressions can be evaluated during translation.* Exactly what that means is (I guess) open to some degree of interpretation. One *could* argue that it implies they *will* be evaluated at compile time; or one *could* argue that they only have to be *potentially* evaluable during compilation.

Comment: @user17732522 OK but again, a constant expression doesnt require it to be ‘evaluated during translation’. In my example we *are* using a constant expression. But it is not mandated that it is evaluated ‘during translation’ and so I wondered how it would be possible if that happened to initialize the array.

Comment: What that Note #1 categorically means is that if something *can't* be evaluated during translation, then it ain't a constant expression.

Comment: @AdrianMole then that seems to mean that it could still evaluated during runtime, even though it can also be evaluated during translation. So my question still stands, I guess

Comment: ... but ❡19 of the same section states: *19 An expression or conversion is manifestly constant-evaluated if it is: ... (19.1) a constant-expression, ...* And, from [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=manifestly+meaning), "manifestly" means "in a way that is clear or obvious to the eye or mind." So, it's all down to the beholder's eye/mind. :)

Comment: If the expression, `e`, in an array declaration of the form, `T x[e];` is *not* clearly and obviously evaluated during the translation phase, then the declaration would not conform to the language Standard ... IMHO.

Comment: @AdrianMole That's what I'm trying to understand. Nowhere does it look like such a scenario would be non-compliant, though...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253054/discussion-between-adrian-mole-and-someonewithpassion).

Comment: Per [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.array#1) the size must be a converted constant expression, meaning the compiler has to evaluate the function call at compile time.

Comment: And what if the compiler does right that, then decides to forget about the evaluation done at compile-time, and re-evaluate at run-time? The scenario would be almost identical. It would still be compliant, would it not?

Comment: @SomeoneWithPassion There is nothing to evaluate at runtime.  the size of an array is part of its type, it has to be known at compile time. In the compiled program types don't exist, so no function call.  It just moves the stack pointer to the correct position.

Comment: @NathanOliver But I don't see anything related to that written in the standard? "The size of an array must be known at compile time". All I see is "The size of the array must be a converted constant expression". And since the compiler must evaluate the expression to see if it is a constant expression, then the evaluation must happen at compile time.
But I see no constraints under which the compiler is disallowed to forget about the evaluation made during compile time, and re-do it during run-time.

Comment: @SomeoneWithPassion Something that is a converted constant expression is something that is known at compile time. There is no need to call it at run time as there is nothing to call.  The array declaration doesn't happen at run time.  All that happens is the stack pointer is adjusted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write

```
int myArray[foo()];
```

this is the syntactical form for a declaration of an array with known bounds. The standard says that the expression used for the size of the array in such a declaration must be a *converted constant expression of type `std::size_t`*.

If it is not such a constant expression, then the program is ill-formed. The standard requires the compiler to issue a diagnostic and doesn't require anything else about the behavior of such a program.

If it is such a constant expression, then the declaration is specified to declare `myArray` as an object of type *array of `int` of size X*, where `X` is the (converted) value of `foo()`.

The rest of the standard describes how arrays of a given size behave, e.g. how it is possible to access their elements at index `0` to `X-1`, how their `sizeof` is `X*sizeof(int)`, etc. The compiler must ensure that executing the program behaves as described by the standard according to these rules.

That's about all that being a constant expression means. Nothing else is required of an implementation.

The way how arrays are specified means however that if the compiler wants to efficiently implement arrays, it effectively needs to know the value of the constant expression `foo()`. For example, it won't be able to reserve enough memory on the stack otherwise and would otherwise need to do something inefficient like calling `alloca` with a runtime calculated value. There is no reason a compiler would want to do that.

Also, because the compiler is required to diagnose whether `foo()` is a constant expression, which in itself effectively requires fully evaluating the expression, it would be stupid of the compiler to not store the calculated value instead of recalculating it at runtime to implement some unusual inefficient form or arrays.

In the end, with a normal implementation of arrays, the size of the array is not a quantity that exists at runtime at all. The size of an array is always fixed by the constant expression in its declaration. There is no condition under which the same array declaration can have two different sizes in a well-formed C++ program. So it would make no sense to keep it variable in an implementation either.

Also there are no VLA in standard C++ and the declaration doesn't use the form for an unbound array, so it isn't either of these. It is just a declaration for an array of size `5`.

Comment: Well, this seems to explain everything that I asked for basically.
- I now get why it wouldn't make sense for the compiler to re-evaluate at run-time (I knew it wouldn't make sense, but not the why)
- So such a compiler would still be compliant. That's what I also wondered about.
- I also completely missed the part that to check whether it is a constant expression, the compiler MUST evaluate the expression. So that's a plus.

Thanks!

Comment: @SomeoneWithPassion "_So such a compiler would still be compliant._": The only thing the standard requires for compliance is for the compiler to issue a diagnostic for ill-formed programs and to guarantee that for well-formed programs, for each possible set of inputs, one of the permitted sets of _observable behaviors_ as the standard describes on the abstract machine, is produced. (Of course if the that is _undefined behavior_ or the program is ill-formed this implies no requirement.) There is nothing in there about how machine code looks or how anything is evaluated in general.